# How to set SearchView TextSize?

Tags: android, searchview

I have a `SearchView` inside a `LinearLayout` and I'm trying to set a different `TextSize` for it (the `SearchView`) but when setting `android:textSize="60sp"` for example, nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="2dp">
<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/search_results"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Does anyone know how to modify the `TextSize` of the control?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could do these using code

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(context);
LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout1.getChildAt(2);
LinearLayout linearLayout3 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout2.getChildAt(1);
AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) linearLayout3.getChildAt(0);
autoComplete.setTextSize(60);
```

Here is another solution

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(context);
AutoCompleteTextView search_text = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
search_text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
search_text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.text_small));
```

Comment: The first method, using sub-linear layouts worked perfectly for me. For whatever reason, the second method using the getIdentifier() produces a null search_text. Either way, thank you for the answer as this was just what I needed to decrease the font size a bit

Comment: NullPointerException from second method

Comment: for the second method to work I used this id:
android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text

Comment: What should I use for androidx?

Comment: @AanalMehta You can use first solution for androidx

Answer (score 67):

You can achieve this using a theme:

in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppSearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView" >
        <item name="android:textSize">60sp</item>
    </style>
```

And using a SearchView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            app:theme="@style/AppSearchView"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
```

Comment: perhaps a better solution

Answer (score 13):

Try my solution (AndroidX).

*styles.xml*

```
 <style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
 </style>
```

*your_layout_name.xml*

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
      app:defaultQueryHint="Search"
      android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle" // Not style!!
      .
      .
      .
         />
```

Answer (score 4):

When using ActionBarSherlock you have to do this:

```
    AutoCompleteTextView searchTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
    searchTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.search_text_color));
```

Comment: Hy. I'm not using ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: The question was about text *size*, not colour. For completeness, the second line in your answer should be something like: `searchTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size))`

Comment: Why the change in text_color? OP just wanted to change the text_size

Answer (score 1):

Though `AutoCompleteTextView` is superclass of `SearchAutoComplete`, `SearchView` use `SearchAutoComplete` rather than `AutoCompleteTextView`. use it and do more.

```
SearchView searchView=...;
SearchView.SearchAutoComplete autoComplete= searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
float textSpSize=10.f;
if (autoComplete!=null){
    autoComplete.setTextSize(textSpSize);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### I've created kotlin extension function

```
fun SearchView.setTextSize(size: Float) {
    findViewById<EditText>(R.id.search_src_text).textSize = size
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this answer [Can we limit the number of character in edittext of SearchView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16033389/838444). It uses [SearchView.OnQueryTextListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html) in order to check if exceeded the limit.