# Is it possible to change the textcolor on an Android SearchView?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview

The SearchView element doesn't have any properties for changing the text color. The default text color is black and doesn't work on our dark background. Is there a way to change the color of the text without resorting to hacks?

I found this similar question related to changing the text size, but so far, it doesn't have any answers:
[How to set SearchView TextSize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535176/how-to-set-searchview-textsize)

Comment: please mention what you have tried.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Check this out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259707/change-appcompats-searchview-text-and-hint-color/66246372#66246372

Answer (score 144):

Add

```
<item name="android:editTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

to the parent theme and that should change the entered text. You can also use

```
<item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
```

to change the hint text color for the SearchView. (Note that you can replace the `@android:color/white` with whatever appropriate value you're hoping to use)

Comment: This fixed it for me, and didn't involve any complicated shenanigans using reflection. Also works with appcompat.

Comment: You can also set android:theme on the searchview to a style that has the android:editTextColor element. This way you only affect that searchview.

Comment: It works! I was using a search view inside a toolbar, extended ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light and added the above item and set the style on the Toolbar widget ;) Works like a charm...

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. Text has still the wrong color. The answer below with setting the hint color programmatically worked for me.

Comment: You are a genius buddy .. thanks a ton for the great solution.

Comment: This will change all edit text color in whole Application. i.e change all the edit text color . not only for Searchview. :(

Comment: Thank You. Use this in a custom theme , apply theme on any activity you want.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it will also change the text color of your `EditText`s. The only solution that has worked for me that changes the `SearchView` text color alone is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40550067/1617737

Comment: I second that the link provided by @ban-geoengineering worked for me

Answer (score 105):

Try something like this :
You would get a handle to the textview from the sdk and then change it since they don't expose it publicly.

```
int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(id);
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: This allways returns null

Comment: Note that if you're using ActionBarSherlock the view IDs will be different.  For example, the lib currently sets the edit text ID to "package:id/abs__search_src_text", which can be accessed directly via R.id.abs__search_src_text.

Comment: Also, what I actually wanted to change was the SearchView hint text color, which is done easily via textView.setHintTextColor().

Comment: This is a very dirty hack. Use android:editTextColor and android:textColorHint instead like akdotcom suggested

Comment: For AndroidX you'll have to use `searchView.findViewById<TextView>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)` to find the TextView

Answer (score 75):

This works for me.

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Comment: This also works if you obtain the view as a TextView or even as an AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: Yes, this is work for me after following the suggestion of @JuanJoséMeleroGómez

Comment: I suppose, this was copied and shortened from my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26251197/2914140.

Answer (score 36):

Thanks to @CzarMatt I added **AndroidX** support.

For me the following works.
I used a code from a link: [Change text color of search hint in actionbar using support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786726/change-text-color-of-search-hint-in-actionbar-using-support-library).

```
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    EditText txtSearch = ((EditText)searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text));
    txtSearch.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));
    txtSearch.setHintTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    txtSearch.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

[Changing action bar searchview hint text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791388/changing-action-bar-searchview-hint-text-color) advices another solution. It works but sets only hint text and color.

```
    searchView.setQueryHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color = #ffffff>" + getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint) + "</font>"));
```

Comment: Use `androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text` if you've migrated your project to AndroidX.

Answer (score 27):

I wanted to do something similar. I finally had to find the `TextView` among the `SearchView` children:

```
for (TextView textView : findChildrenByClass(searchView, TextView.class)) {
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

If you want the util method:

```
public static <V extends View> Collection<V> findChildrenByClass(ViewGroup viewGroup, Class<V> clazz) {

    return gatherChildrenByClass(viewGroup, clazz, new ArrayList<V>());
}

private static <V extends View> Collection<V> gatherChildrenByClass(ViewGroup viewGroup, Class<V> clazz, Collection<V> childrenFound) {

    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        final View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(child.getClass())) {
            childrenFound.add((V)child);
        }
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            gatherChildrenByClass((ViewGroup) child, clazz, childrenFound);
        }
    }

    return childrenFound;
}
```

Comment: I too was getting the null exception with previous solutions, and this worked for me!

Comment: This should be marked as accepted answer. The above one gives null. Thanks for the good work buddy :)

Comment: This solution is so disgusting but its the only one that actually works and it is Android team to blame!

Comment: How would we access the search icon with this ?

Comment: AMAZING !  The best solution ever ...all this xml design is....

Answer (score 18):

You can override the default color using the **`android:theme`** attribute in the View.

If you are using a **`Toolbar`** or **`MaterialToolbar`**:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Toobar"
    ...>
```

or:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Toobar"
    ...>
```

where the Theme overlay with a **Material Components Theme** is:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.Toobar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <!-- Text color -->
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/....</item>
    <!-- Hint text color -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

with an AppCompat theme:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.Toobar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light.*">
    <!-- Text color -->
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/....</item>
    <!-- Hint text color -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

[image]

---

If you are using a **`SearchView`** in your layout you can do something similar:

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.SearchView"
```

with

```
   <style name="ThemeOverlay.SearchView" parent="">
        <!-- Text color -->
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/...</item>
        <!-- Hint text color -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/...</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

This is best achieved through custom styles.  Overload the action bar widget style with your own custom style.  For holo light with dark action bar, put this in your own styles file such as `res/values/styles_mytheme.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.MyTheme.Widget</item>
    <!-- your other custom styles -->
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyTheme.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
    <!-- your other custom widget styles -->
</style>
```

Make sure your application is using theme custom theme as described in [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme)

Answer (score 16):

You can do so by setting the `editTextColor` attribute in the style.

```
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Some.Relevant.Parent">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/some_color</item>
</style>
```

and you apply this style to `Toolbar` or the `SearchView` in the layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: +1 This trumps all solutions involving findViewById imho. View styling should be used whenever possible.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Very clean and easy.

Answer (score 10):

if you use - android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
editText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

in Kotlin

```
val searchView = SearchView(this)
val editText = searchView.findViewById<EditText>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
editText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
```

You should rather start using androidx support libraries now

Answer (score 8):

Create a Style for your `Toolbar`

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/some_color</item>
</style>
```

And set it as the theme for the `Toolbar`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using the android.support.v7.widget.SearchView, it's possible without having to use reflection.

Here's how I'm doing it in my app:

```
EditText text = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
ImageView searchCloseIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
View searchPlate = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);

if (searchPlate != null) {
    searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_background);
}

if (text != null){
    text.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white));
    text.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

    SpannableStringBuilder magHint = new SpannableStringBuilder("  ");
    magHint.append(resources.getString(R.string.search));

    Drawable searchIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_view_search);
    int textSize = (int) (text.getTextSize() * 1.5);
    searchIcon.setBounds(0, 0, textSize, textSize);
    magHint.setSpan(new ImageSpan(searchIcon), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // Set the new hint text
    text.setHint(magHint);

}

if (searchCloseIcon != null){
    searchCloseIcon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_close));
}
```

They don't expose the ids publicly for the non appcompat SearchView, but they do for AppCompat if you know where to look. :)

Comment: This actually works pretty well on various devices. Nice one.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem, and this works for me.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.customer_menu, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView       = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_customer_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        //Applies white color on searchview text
        int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(id);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        return true;
}
```

Comment: I allways get null on: (TextView) searchView.findViewById(id);

Answer (score 4):

If you base your app theme on the holo theme you will get a white instead of a black text in your SearchView

`<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">`

I did not find any other way to change the textcolor of the searchview without using dirty hacks.

Comment: This didn't work. I was hoping it would, since it's a lot cleaner than manually searching for a "magic" view ID. I tried several themes, with an activity whose layout has a dark background, but none of them produced anything other than black text in the SearchView.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible using following method.

```
public static EditText setHintEditText(EditText argEditText, String argHintMessage, boolean argIsRequire) {
    try {
        if (argIsRequire) {
            argHintMessage = "   " + argHintMessage;
            //String text = "<font color=#8c8c8c>"+argHintMessage+"</font> <font color=#cc0029>*</font>";
            String text = "<font color=#8c8c8c>" + argHintMessage + "</font>";
            argEditText.setHint(Html.fromHtml(text));
        } else {
            argEditText.setHint(argHintMessage);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return argEditText;
}
```

Calling of this method look like this..

```
metLoginUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.etLoginUserName);
    metLoginPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.etLoginPassword);

    /**Set the hint in username and password edittext*/
    metLoginUserName=HotSpotStaticMethod.setHintEditText(metLoginUserName, getString(R.string.hint_username),true);
    metLoginPassword=HotSpotStaticMethod.setHintEditText(metLoginPassword, getString(R.string.hint_password),true);
```

using it i have successfully add red color * mark in hint using this method.
You should change this method according to your requirement.
I hope its helpful to you ....:)

Comment: it's somewhat a little complicated to me.

Comment: String text = "<font color=#8c8c8c>"+HintMessage+"</font>";
        argEditText.setHint(Html.fromHtml(text)); your can also use only these two line code for setting color hint

Comment: `SearchAutoComplete autoCompleteView = (SearchAutoComplete) mSearchView   .findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.search_src_text);autoCompleteView.setHintTextColor(R.color.hint_text_color);`  that's my solution, but i think yours is better than mine, i'll use your solution,thank you.

Comment: @gaols have you got solution..?

Comment: @gaols,where is your "com.android.internal.R.id.search_src_text"?

Comment: @gaols answer is for appcompat-v7. See abc_search_view.xml, within is a view with class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete

Answer (score 4):

Most cleanest way is:

Toolbar uses theme ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.Actionbar.

Now make child of it like:

toolbarStyle parent "ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.Actionbar"

add this item in that style

item name "android:editTextColor">yourcolor

Done.

One more very important thing is, in toolbar put the layout_height ="?attr/actionbarSize". By default it is wrap_content.For me text was not even visible in searchview it fixed that problem.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me, if you use
**androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView** apply **androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text** to identify the searchview, no returns null in the **textView**

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    textView.setHintTextColorstrong text(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this one, it's right. :D

```
AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
searchText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(color.black));
searchText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(color.black));
```

Answer (score 3):

Change color of typed text:

```
((EditText)((SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView)).findViewById(((SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView)).getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null))).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Change color of hint text:

```
((EditText)((SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView)).findViewById(((SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView)).getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null))).setHintTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes we can,

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.sv_symbol);
```

To apply the white color for the SerachView Text,

```
int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(id);
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Happy coding !!!!

Answer (score 3):

this is working for me.

```
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);   
searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) 
{
    searchEditText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.c_trasnparent));
    searchEditText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    searchEditText.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,R.drawable.ic_cross,null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 1):

A `SearchView` object extends from `LinearLayout`, so it holds other views. The trick is to find the view holding the hint text and change the colour programmatically. The problem with trying to find the view by id is that the id is dependent from the theme used in the application. So depending on the theme used, the `findViewById(int id)` method might return `null`. A better approach that works with every theme is to traverse the view hierarchy and find the widget containing the hint text:

```
// get your SearchView with its id
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
// traverse the view to the widget containing the hint text
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)searchView.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout)ll.getChildAt(2);
LinearLayout ll3 = (LinearLayout)ll2.getChildAt(1);
SearchView.SearchAutoComplete autoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)ll3.getChildAt(0);
// set the hint text color
autoComplete.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(Color.WHITE));
// set the text color
autoComplete.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Using this method, you can also change the look of other widgets in the `SearchView` hierarchy, such as the `EditText` holding the search query. Unless Google decides to change the view hierarchy of a `SearchView` shortly, you should be able to change the appearance of the widget with this method for some time.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to customize searchview by using appcompat v7 library.I used appcompat v7 library and defined custom style for it.
In drawable folder put bottom_border.xml file which looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item>
  <shape >
      <solid android:color="@color/blue_color" />
  </shape>
 </item>
 <item android:bottom="0.8dp"
   android:left="0.8dp"
   android:right="0.8dp">
  <shape >
      <solid android:color="@color/background_color" />
  </shape>
 </item>

 <!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars -->
 <item android:bottom="2.0dp">
  <shape >
      <solid android:color="@color/main_accent" />
  </shape>
  </item>
 </layer-list>
```

In values folder styles_myactionbartheme.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
  <style name="AppnewTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/ActionBarWidget</item>
  </style> 
  <!-- Actionbar Theme -->
  <style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/main_accent</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:icon">@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_light</item> -->
  </style> 
  <style name="ActionBarWidget" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- SearchView customization-->
     <!-- Changing the small search icon when the view is expanded -->
    <!-- <item name="searchViewSearchIcon">@drawable/ic_action_search</item> -->
     <!-- Changing the cross icon to erase typed text -->
   <!--   <item name="searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/ic_action_remove</item> -->
     <!-- Styling the background of the text field, i.e. blue bracket -->
    <item name="searchViewTextField">@drawable/bottom_border</item>
     <!-- Styling the text view that displays the typed text query -->
    <item name="searchViewAutoCompleteTextView">@style/AutoCompleteTextView</item>        
  </style>

    <style name="AutoCompleteTextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
   <!--   <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item> -->
    <!-- <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/search_view_selected_text</item> -->
  </style>
 </resources>
```

I defined custommenu.xml  file for displaying menu:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:com.example.actionbartheme="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >  

  <item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/search_title"
      android:icon="@drawable/search_buttonn"
      com.example.actionbartheme:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        com.example.actionbartheme:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>        
  </menu>
```

Your activity should extend ActionBarActivity instead of Activity.
 Here is onCreateOptionsMenu method.

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
  {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.custommenu, menu);
  }
```

In manifest file:

```
  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppnewTheme" >
```

For more information see this url:
Here http://www.jayway.com/2014/06/02/android-theming-the-actionbar/

Answer (score 1):

for appcompat-v7 Toolbar with searchView (provided via MenuItemCompat):

Setting the Toolbar theme to @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light will yield dark color (black) for the hint text and for the entered text, but won't affect the cursor* color. Accordingly, setting the Toolbar theme to @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark will yield light color (white) for the hint text and the entered text, the cursor* will be white anyway.

Customising the above themes:

android:textColorPrimary --> color of the entered text

editTextColor --> color of the entered text (will override  the affect of android:textColorPrimary if set)

android:textColorHint --> color of the hint

*note: Am yet to determine how the Cursor color can be controlled (without using the reflection solution).

Comment: The cursor color comes from colorControlActivated

Answer (score 1):

By using this I was able to change the typed color text in search view

```
AutoCompleteTextView typed_text = (AutoCompleteTextView) inputSearch.findViewById(inputSearch.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
typed_text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow. A lot of answer. It gets color value from your primary color.

Change it, and its done!

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().setTheme(R.style.YourTheme_Searching);
}
```

Styles;

```
<style name="YourTheme.Searching" parent="YourTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

change searchView style in toolbar with androidx.

firstly,set search view style in your toolbar Style (change parent them with your own app base them):

```
     <!-- toolbar style -->
      <style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">     
          <!-- search view about -->
          <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/colorWhitePrimaryText</item>
          <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorWhiteSecondaryText</item>
          <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/drawable_cursor_white</item>
          <item name="closeIcon">@mipmap/ic_close</item>
          <item name="searchHintIcon">@mipmap/ic_search_white</item>
          <item name="searchIcon">@mipmap/ic_search_white</item>
          <item name="android:longClickable">false</item>
          <item name="android:queryHint">@string/toolbar_search</item>
      </style>
```

then, use it in your toolbar layout:

```
android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
```

with this, you can change most style of searchView except for query hint.

finally set query hint at your toolbar menu's options:

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.toolbar_search:
                SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
                searchView.setQueryHint("default query");
                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                return true;
                default:
                    return false;
        }
```

Comment: Did you mean to post something under "searchView style"?

Comment: I have completed and simplified my solution,maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin way of changing text/hint color using extension

```
fun SearchView.changeColors(color: Int) {
    val editText = this.findViewById<EditText>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
    editText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color))
    editText.setHintTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Kotlin ad AndroidX, just try the following:

```
val id: Int = binding.searchView.context
        .resources
        .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null)
val editText: EditText = binding.searchView.findViewById(id)
editText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
editText.setHintTextColor(Color.BLACK)
```

Comment: using getIdentifier is not recommended anymore

Answer (score 0):

```
searchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);

SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchText = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) searchView
      .findViewById(org.holoeverywhere.R.id.search_src_text);
searchText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

I am using Holoeverywhere Library. Note the **org.holoeverywhere.R.id.search_src_text**

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from a blog post. See [here](http://www.jayway.com/2014/06/02/android-theming-the-actionbar/).

Basically you style searchViewAutoCompleteTextView and have android:actionBarWidgetTheme inherit the style.

Answer (score 0):

it works with me

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.getActionView().findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me

```
((EditText)searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text));
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Kotlin Language**

```
    searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchView_Contacts)
    // change color
    val id = searchView.context.resources
        .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null)

    val textView = searchView.findViewById<View>(id) as TextView

    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can implement like this class to change font color and image ::

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView.SearchAutoComplete;


public class MySearchView {
    public static SearchView getSearchView(Context context, String strHint) {
        SearchView searchView = new SearchView(context);
        searchView.setQueryHint(strHint);
        searchView.setFocusable(true);
        searchView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        searchView.requestFocus();
        searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();

         ImageView searchBtn = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_button);
         searchBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_search);


         ImageView searchBtnClose = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_close_btn);
         searchBtnClose.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cancel_search_bar);


         SearchAutoComplete searchText = (SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);

        searchText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(color.white));

        return searchView;
    }


    public static SearchView getSearchView(Context context, int strHintRes) {
        return getSearchView(context, context.getString(strHintRes));
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you guys.
:D

Answer (score -2):

I tried and find one solution for this. I think it will help you..

```
searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

[image]

Comment: the question says text color not background color

Answer (score -2):

This Way :)

```
View searchPlate = searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
if (searchPlate!=null) {
    searchPlate.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    int searchTextId = searchPlate.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    TextView searchText = (TextView) searchPlate.findViewById(searchTextId);
    if (searchText != null) {
        searchText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        searchText.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
return ;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: thanx for help .

Answer (score -3):

Casting the *SearchView* to *TextView* allows you to use *TextView*'s methods to change its colour:

```
((TextView) searchView).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
((TextView) searchView).setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```