# Change color of Autosuggestbox in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to change the layout and color of the suggestion box I get in my Google Maps-API based app in Android Studio. I have no idea whether I should look into the code of Google Maps or somewhere else.

[the link contains an image with the suggestbox I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfq5r.png)

This is the code of the TextView:

```
        <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_magnify"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#ecf0f1"
        android:id="@+id/input_search"
        android:background="@null"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
```

And I use the PlaceAutocompleteAdapter to autosuggest the possible locations.

Comment: That depends on how you implemented it. Please show us some codes. You can start by that `SearchView`. Then we'll be able to help you better. Also, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240200/changing-the-background-color-of-searchview-autocomplete-dropdown

Comment: @Mohsen I edited the question. I'm sorry I didn't know where to look so I could add any code. Hope you can do something more with this!

Comment: It's alright, you set the background `@null`. Could you change the color of this to for ex. : `#FFFFFF` and see what happens? This should make the background white.

Comment: @Mohsen No this doesn't seem to work. This background color refers to the background color of the textfield. Therefore this one is .@null. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I do not have a SearchView. I achieved the searching option with         android:imeOptions="actionSearch". Also, I don't see how the link you provided could help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by styling the dropdown popup.
I added **android:popupBackground="#2d3e50"** to the AutoCompleteTextView-style which changed the color to the one 
I needed.