# SearchView edittext is always null

Tags: android, searchview

I always get that textView is null when doing this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
                .getActionView(searchItem);

        int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(id);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: Finding de textView wich has the text that I want to change, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14364222/1680787

Comment: [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String))

Comment: Did you try to Log id, and what it returns?

Comment: I think it depends on SDK or theme you are using. I checked examples, some people used android:id/search_plate, some others used android:id/search_src_txt

Comment: If it only happens when the app is obfuscated, try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23934038/684582

Answer (score 36):

I'm using action bar of appcompat v7 and my solusion is:

```
TextView searchText = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Unbelievable IT WORKED!!! YOU Saved my Life! Where do u guys discover that stuff??

Comment: Android is open source :)

Comment: Use for id `androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text` if you are using AndroidX

Answer (score 23):

It's a `EditText` not a `TextView`.

Try something like that:

```
int id = searchView.getContext()
                   .getResources()
                   .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(id);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: An EditText is a TextView, actually. It inherits TextView. That's why they have a lot of the same methods. EditText is just editable.

Comment: @afollestad You´re right. But in my case it has worked with an EditView but not with a TextView. I dont know exactly why. Maybe one of the magical android mysteries again.

Comment: Been searching for HOURS until I found this buried here. Just wanted to thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AndroidX then you can do like this in kotlin.

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
            val searchItem: MenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            val searchView: SearchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
            val searchText: TextView = searchView?.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
            searchText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            searchText.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner_background)

            return true
        }
```