# Android text does not appear when typing

Tags: android, textview, android-4.4-kitkat, searchview, invisible

I have run into an issue which seems to come from SearchViews.
It seems to only happen on 4.4.4.
Basically when I open a SearchView and type into it, the text does not appear. I can see from debugging that when I type anything, the search view is correctly receiving it, it's just not displaying inside the search view.
Any ideas on what can cause this?

EDIT

Just noticed I can select the text and I can see it, so it seems the issue is that the SearchView is not using the theme we have selected and is using white text instead, which is why its invisible.
Is there something with 4.4.4 that causes this?

Comment: try changing the textcolor to black :)

Comment: @Dev yeah just wondering what is best way, could you change it in the Styles file at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, the text was simply appearing as white, so for some reason on 4.4.4 it wasn't following our theme.

The accepted answer here: [Change TextColor in SearchView using Android Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156680/change-textcolor-in-searchview-using-android-toolbar)

is what I done to fix the issue.