# How to change SearchView textcolor?

Tags: android, searchview

My [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView) is located in a LinearLayout / RelativeLayout rather than the action bar.

Its default text color is white, how to change it?

Answer (score 47):

Digging into the source code of the appcompat SearchView I found that it uses an `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` which by default uses the `autoCompleteTextView` style.

Creating a different autocomplete style and setting it in the app theme solved the problem for me.

```
<style name="SearchAutoCompleteTextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/my_hint_color</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
    <item name="autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/SearchAutoCompleteTextView</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer - if you want to change the text/hint color for a android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Comment: This works, and you can set it for individual searchViews by adding xml ```app:theme="@style/SearchViewTextTheme"``` instead of applying it to the whole ```AppTheme```

Comment: You're the MVP, none of the other solutions worked, but this one does perfectly

Answer (score 38):

For Androidx Library

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
EditText searchEditText = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

For Android Support Library

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Comment: Should I add this code in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method?

Answer (score 10):

Try this,

```
SearchView searchView= (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
int id = searchView.getContext()
               .getResources()
               .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(id);
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

or

```
((EditText)  searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text))
       .setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

or

```
searchView.setQueryHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color = #ffffff>" +    
              getResources().getString(R.string.your_str) + "</font>"));
```

This may helps you.

Answer (score 7):

For me worked next approach:

1.add style into your styles.xml

```
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/light_gray</item>
</style>
```

2.add this line in your SearchView layout code

```
app:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle"
```

Answer (score 5):

I would do this kind of job through the xml layout file. This can be found in the res/layout folder.

You would need to do something similar to the following:

Add this to the parent theme.

```
<item name="android:editTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

This should change the entered text.

You can also use something like this:

```
<item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
```

It will change the hint text for the SearchView.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

Just override the default color using the `android:theme` attribute:

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.SearchView"
```

with

```
   <style name="ThemeOverlay.SearchView" parent="">
        <!-- Text color -->
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/...</item>
        <!-- Hint text color -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/...</item>
    </style>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this, if its not working try to change your theme.

```
((EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

or try like this

```
searchView.setQueryHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color = #ffffff>" + getResources().getString(R.string.hintSearchMess) + "</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61049160/3409600) colors of search icon, search hint icon, close icon, plate, query hint color, query color are changed

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
EditText searchEditText = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
searchEditText.setHint("Search");
searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Comment: what about cursor color and close/clear icon color?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on latest sdk34.

in the theme.xml

```
    <style name="ThemeSearchView" parent="TextAppearance.Material3.SearchView">
         <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/black</item>
         <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/secondary</item>
     </style>
```

and in your searchView layout

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeSearchView"
```