# How to change SearchView elements' color?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-search

I want to use SearchView in my project, but I have a problem with elements' color. Let me show you: its fragmentDialog where I have my SearchView
[image: You can see what I mean here]

I dont need to change bg color. The next picture is for example. I want to see SearchView elements without black bg.
[image: The color of the elements is white]

I have tried to

- change theme
- change style
- change tint

but nothing is working. The search icon and anoter elements still white. Maybe I'm losing something? Can I do this in XML? Please, help me.

Comment: Do you want to set icon and background color dynamically ????

Comment: No, I dont. I want to set it in XML and dont touch it anymore, if it's possible

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

try with this style in your searchview,

Before expanding searchview --->
[image]

After expanding searchview --->

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            style="@style/SearchViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end" />

<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <!-- Gets rid of the search icon -->
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_search</item>
    <!-- Gets rid of the "underline" in the text -->
    <item name="queryBackground">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Gets rid of the search icon when the SearchView is expanded -->
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
    <!-- The hint text that appears when the user has not typed anything -->
    <item name="queryHint">@string/search_hint</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I think you are not using android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Comment: yea, you're right. A found it 2 hours before your ansver :D
http://stackoverflow.com/a/40791256/7138308

Comment: The text color ends up being white.

Comment: you are not changing any colors here, offtopic

Comment: @user924, what do you want to do exactly? let me know. IMO it is changing color of the background for sure because I've tested it.

Comment: @Bhavnik here is the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54273767/7767664

Answer (score 50):

In this answer I assume that, the `SearchView` is added inside `Toolbar` and `AppTheme` is a child of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="AppTheme">
    <!--This line changes the color of text in Toolbar-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/green</item>
    <!--This line changes the color of icons in toolbar (back, overflow menu icons)-->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

Now use the `AppTheme.Toolbar` as your toolbar's theme.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar" />
```

Comment: But what if I use SearchView not in the Toolbar? Will it be work?

Comment: If the `SearchView` is a menu item shown in `Toolbar` it would work.

Comment: thanks brother.But i try with programatically but not worked

Comment: This should be accepted answer after so long time research!
Thanks for the solution!

Comment: offtopic, the question is not about search in toolbar

Answer (score 17):

You can modify your search view with a costume style in `styles.xml' :

```
<style name="AppSearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView" >
    <!-- Text Size -->
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textSizePrimary</item>
    <!-- Query Text Color -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <!-- Hint Color -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/textColorDisabled</item>
    <!-- Icon Color -->
    <item name="android:tint">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

then use this style in your search view :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    app:theme="@style/AppSearchView" />
```

Comment: should be accept, we only one answer that shows how to change colors, `parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView"` is very important to make it all work, works fine with `<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView ...  />`

Answer (score 6):

`Searchview` which comes with support library has features to change icons

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
            app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close_black"
            app:commitIcon=""
            app:goIcon=""
            app:searchHintIcon=""
            app:voiceIcon=""
    >
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int searchiconId = view.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button",null,null);
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(searchiconId);
Drawable whiteIcon = img.getDrawable();
whiteIcon.setTint(Color.RED); //Whatever color you want it to be
img.setImageDrawable(whiteIcon);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to add those lines to style.

`android:textColorPrimary` changes text that user inputs in EditText.
`android:textColorSecondary` changes back arrow, "remove text" cross and small search icon before the hint.

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, what was my problem. I used android.widget.SearchView instead of android.support.v7.widget.SearchView. I changed SearchView and after that proposed solution started to work.

If somebody can explain why styles and different things did not work or can give me a link, I'll be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you if you want to change color of magnifying glass in Search view.
if you use Material theme than this

```
 ImageView icon = album_search.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.search_button);
        Drawable whiteIcon = icon.getDrawable();
        whiteIcon.setTint(Color.BLACK); //Whatever color you want it to be
        icon.setImageDrawable(whiteIcon);
```

and if Appcompact theme than just change `com.google.android.material.R.id.search_button` to  `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button`

Thats it

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I've changed colors of search icon, search hint icon, close icon, plate, query hint color, query color

```
view!!.findViewById<EditText>(
            searchView.context.resources.getIdentifier(
                "android:id/search_src_text",
                null,
                null
            )
        ).apply {
            setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.darkThemeIconColor))
            setHintTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.colorAccent))
        }

        view!!.findViewById<ImageView>(
            searchView.context.resources.getIdentifier(
                "android:id/search_button",
                null, null
            )
        ).imageTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(
            ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.darkThemeIconColor)
        )
        val mDrawable = SearchView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mSearchHintIcon")
        mDrawable.isAccessible = true
        val drawable = mDrawable.get(searchView) as Drawable
        drawable.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(
            ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.darkThemeIconColor),
            BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP
        )
        view!!.findViewById<ImageView>(
            searchView.context.resources.getIdentifier(
                "android:id/search_close_btn",
                null, null
            )
        ).imageTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(
            ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.darkThemeIconColor)
        )
        view!!.findViewById<View>(
            searchView.context.resources.getIdentifier(
                "android:id/search_plate",
                null, null
            )
        ).backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(
            ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.darkThemeIconColor)
        )
```