# How to change the color of searchHintIcon in SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I want to change the colour of searchHintIcon in `SearchView`, not  searching colour

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change SearchView elements' color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786189/how-to-change-searchview-elements-color)

Comment: that question is for search icon color not for searchHintIcon color @ADM

Comment: You can use a drawable for `searchHintIcon` attribute .give it a try.

Comment: want to change the default icon color. and searchHintIcon is for api above 21

Comment: No sure about this but have a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22320059/4168607) . You can then set new icon with `ColorFilter`.

Comment: @ADM its not working and giving me null pointer exception

Comment: Try with `android.support.v7.appcompat.SearchView` And `ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);`  ..

Comment: Already tired not working.@ADM