# Text input in SearchView doesn't show

Tags: android, searchview, android-search

I noticed a couple days ago that inputting text in my `SearchView` doesn't show up. Maybe this problem started longer ago and I hadn't noticed it, but I know that everything was working well when I first set up search functionality.

Here is a screenshot (I have already entered text, and you can see that it is not showing):

[image]

I have already tried to change the colour of the text on the `SearchView`, with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11321129/4230345), and I've also tried changing the text colour in my searchable configuration XML file. After I found that none of these work, I undid my changes so that you can see the code I currently have below:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) { 

    ...

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchResultsActivity.class)));
    // Note: getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()) will not work on all flavours
    // because of a difference in app IDs

}
```

Note that I've used `new ComponentName(...)` instead of `getSearchableInfo(getComponentName())` since I use different package names in my different flavours.

The activity above is where the `SearchView` is displayed. The results are shown in another activity.

**searchable.xml**

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    ...

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />
    </activity>

    ...

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.filter.SearchResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results"
        android:parentActivityName=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Search">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.companyname.appname.ui.MainActivity" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    ...
```

**styles.xml**  (the activity containing the `SearchView` uses `AppTheme.NavDrawer`)

```
...

<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">?colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NavDrawer">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
</style>

...
```

**v21/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NavDrawer">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

....
```

**activity_main_filterable.xml** (the layout that my activity uses)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <include layout="@layout/activity_main_content" />

    <include layout="@layout/navdrawer"
    android:id="@+id/navigationView" />

    <include layout="@layout/filter_drawer"
        android:id="@+id/filter_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**activity_main_content.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
            <include layout="@layout/blank" /> <!-- This is to prevent bugs -->
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_misc_no_results"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_no_results"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            style="@style/AppTheme.RecyclerView.StandardList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas on what might be going on or how I should solve it?

Comment: Can you post your style.xml?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari See my updated my question :)

Comment: can you post your layout?

Comment: Can you check using Show Layout Bounds from Developer Options, if the SerachView is there as a rectangular view?

Comment: add following code to your toolbar:  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"

Comment: @MidasLefko I've updated my question with the relevant layout files.

Comment: Did you try my answer below?

Comment: @MidasLefko  Not yet, just about to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue, and for me it was because I had set my toolbar height to wrap_content. Try giving it a size, like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    />
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked for me. Do you know why though?

Comment: No idea. I spent hours experimenting and that't the only thing that worked.

Comment: I still don't have any concrete reason to why it's happening, but coordinator layout could be a potential culprit causing this weird behaviour. If i am using a simple linear layout, SearchView is working fine then.

Answer (score 5):

This is the code I use for my recent project and it's work fine:

First define `search_menu.xml` (make sure use android `supportV7`) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_gray"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Then define in your `onCreateOptionMenu` of your Activity:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.search));
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class)));
searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.search));
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
searchView.setIconified(false);
```

Also my Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray_lightest"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" />
```

Add meta-data to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.SearchActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"
            android:value=".ui.activity.SearchActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Amir, however I found Midas's solution to work for me.