# SearchView not shown in toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-search

Hi I am trying to show `SearchView` in my toolbar. In case I use a custom layout instead of `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` it shows up. Please find the code below.

**menu_search_page.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MyActivity" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

**Activity**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_page_layout);
    activity = this;
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.new_logo);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search_page, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/zpwrsg/add-search-function-to-list-view-in-android

Comment: set Height for your toolbar wil fix the problem **android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38638614/1462770