# Android SearchView not showing text when typing

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

I realized `SearchView` like Google says:

Created `searchable.xml` in `res/xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer" />
```

Created menu item in `res/menu/second_activity_menu`:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/second_toolbar_search"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Change my `AndroidManifest`:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

And realized my `SecondActivity` class which extends `AppCompatActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.second_activity_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.second_toolbar_search).getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    return true;
}
```

As a result I have this:

[image: Toolbar]

After clicling on the search icon I have this:

[image: SearchView]

When I start typing something, it doesn't show and it doesn't show "clear" icon and mic icon either. But I added them in `searchable.xml`.

Thanks for any ideas or code.

**ADD:** maybe the reason is with toolbar style?

**ADD 2:** toolbar, but I don't think that it is nessesary

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        local:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Comment: have you checked the color ?

Comment: Did you check the text color? It might be white. You need to change the text color to black.

Comment: @ReazMurshed didn't help

Comment: @BasilBattikhi changed to black. didn't help

Comment: @AlexBoyko try my answer and please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text input in SearchView doesn't show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575061/text-input-in-searchview-doesnt-show)

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19796417/1276636) make the cursor visible? Also, you should post your app's theme (from styles.xml).

Answer (score 3):

Give a toolbar any explicit `layout_height`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    ...
/>
```

P.S. I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38638149/746347) and voted to close this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can guess, you have your `SearchView` working perfectly, but its not visible as the icons and the text colour is white. So I would like to tell you about how you can change the icon and text colours of your `SearchView`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.second_activity_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    // Set text colour 
    SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchAutoComplete.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    searchAutoComplete.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    View searchplate = (View)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
    searchplate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.texfield_searchview_holo_light);
    // Clear search or close icon
    ImageView searchCloseIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
    searchCloseIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.clear_search);

    // Voice icon
    ImageView voiceIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_voice_btn);
    voiceIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_voice_search);

    // Search icon
    ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
    searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_search);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

You hard to customize the `SearchView` from xml. So follow the programmed solution instead.

Comment: maybe problem with toolbar? maybe I should use different style or use ActionBar. I don't know what's the matter

Comment: You can change the color of the Toolbar too to see what happens. The idea is to make the contrast.

Comment: changed to black. then I typing text, there's nothing happen in SearchView. and there's no voice icon too

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the case, but in my case there was some other View that was removing the focus from SearchView right after clicking on the search icon, which gave me the same result as your second image.

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu)
    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    val searchView = searchItem.actionView as? SearchView
    searchView?.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, _ ->
        // My ScrollView was requesting focus
    }
    return true
}
```

Strangely enough this opens a perfectly working virtual keyboard - with input feedback sound and everything - but all that was typed with it doesn't show anywhere on the screen. Even `searchView.setOnQueryTextListener()` isn't triggered by the input, meaning that the typed text goes to some void and is not used at all.

Using `searchView.requestFocus()` after all Views were done with their focuses worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution in my case was to set

```
searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    searchView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            searchView.isIconified = false
        }
        false
    }

    searchView.setOnClickListener {
        searchView.isIconified = false
    }
```