# Search view input text color

Tags: android, android-search

In below image we can see that search text is black and also white and both the android version are different one is kitkat and other is oreo.
i want input text in white in kitkat version too.

[image: Below is the image]

Comment: have you set the textColor to white anywhere or it is being picked up by default?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26897024/5167909

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a style for your toolbar in styles.xml:

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

or

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

and apply it in your toolbar:

```
android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
```

Comment: Try the 2nd style

Answer (score 0):

You can also set color by having a version check.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    // Set you SearchView hint color to white for and above kitkat version
} else {
    // Set you SearchView hint color to white for other versions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to change searchview text color in Java:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.bluapp.androidview.R;

public class SearchViewActivity5 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SearchView search;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_view5);
        search = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search);
        EditText editText = (EditText)search.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        editText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    }
}
```

See here:
https://inducesmile.com/android-programming/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-searchview-in-android/