# How to change the text color of SearchView?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, styles, searchview

I'm trying to set the text color of the SearchViews of my app to white. I've added to my app's main theme "searchViewStyle" to define the style of every one.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/CustomSearchView</item>
</style>
```

Then I created the "CustomSearchView" style, in the same file.

```
<style name="CustomSearchView" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_small_search</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
    <item name="editTextColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

And this is what I have in the menu item:

```
<menu 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/appbarSearch"
        android:title="@string/buscar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_small_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        />

</menu>
```

As you can see, I've tried with "editTextColor", "textColor" and "hintTextColor", but none of those options have actually worked. ¿So what else can I do to customize the color?

Comment: here, everything you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321129/is-it-possible-to-change-the-textcolor-on-an-android-searchview

Comment: I found that post yesterday, when I was trying to solve the issue by myself. The problem is that it's from 8 years ago. I've tried almost everything posted there and I keep reaching dead ends, probably because since then, Android has been updated and paths, objects and methods have changed.

Comment: I tried and it's work fine

Comment: Which method did you use?

Comment: I cant get this to work either.