# SearchView text color is not changing

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have a AppCompat SearchView and I wanted to change the color of the text in the SearchView. So I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26897024/16731286).

So I typed the answer in my themes.xml and in the layout preview, the text color was black. But when I tested it on the emulator, the text color was white. I am attaching two screenshots as well.

[XML Layout Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cbeM.jpg)

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7ufU.jpg)

What is the problem?

Comment: consider using `app:textColorHint` instead of `android:textColorHint`

Comment: @snachmsm It is displaying Cannot resolve symbol 'app:textColorHint'

Comment: have you declared `app` namespace in this XML? (`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` for first root view in this file)

Comment: @snachmsm It is in the styles.xml file

Comment: I have also put namespace.. But then also the same error is showing..

Comment: Please respond>>

Comment: in `styles.xml` file add `<item name="editTextColor">@color/somecolor</item>` without any prefix (don't remove line with prefix, keep both), thats my only clue...

Comment: @snachmsm Done. Check the answer below

Comment: glad you've figured this out :) good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Create a new theme with the parent `Widget.AppCompat.SearchView` and then you can customize it's font, text size, text color etc.

Code;

```
<style name="SearchViewTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/somecolor</item>
    <item name="editTextColor">@color/somecolor</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/somefont</item>
</style>
```

Comment: for full backward and forward compatibility duplicate color params - one with `android:` prefix and one without. so there should be e.g. `"android:textColorHint"` AND `"textColorHint"` pointing on same color. and you are good to go :)

Comment: Ok @snachmsm Good advice