# Styling android search view and drop down list in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, searchview, android-toolbar

In my app, I have a searchview that displays search suggestions. I want the dropdown/spinner and text to be a particular color. Currently the only change I've been able to make is the text color of the inputted text via the following:

```
   <style name="MyApp.AutoCompleteTextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/myBackgroundColor</item>
  </style>
```

The app currently displays the searchview results like this:

[image: Here is how it currently looks]

What I would like to know is how would I go about changing parts like the searchHint color, the drop down background and the drop down item text color?

I am targeting API 19+

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So after a lot of searching, the closest solution I can find to this is as follows (thanks to [GZ95's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15108885/2879847)!):

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(context);
LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout1.getChildAt(2);
LinearLayout linearLayout3 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout2.getChildAt(1);
AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) linearLayout3.getChildAt(0);
//Set the input text color
autoComplete.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
// set the hint text color
autoComplete.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
//Some drawable (e.g. from xml)
autoComplete.setDropDownBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drop_down_bg);
```

It's not the most elegant but it has worked for me. The only question I have outstanding is how to change the suggested item text color. I am welcome to hear more optimal solutions to this problem

Comment: jedikv here try a cleaner soution:  `SearchView.SearchAutoComplete autoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);  
autoComplete.setDropDownBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drop_down_bg);`

Comment: This was the only solution that have worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

In your styles.xml, set the following to your AppTheme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/myDropDownItemStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="myDropDownItemStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondary_text_default_material_light</item>
</style>
```

This can change the drop down item text color. Have a try.

Comment: How about without AppCompat?

Comment: @Yar   change the `myDropDownItemStyle` 's parent style to the non-AppCompat style. What's your base theme?

Comment: Hi. My parent main style is android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar.  Now I tried to use style <name="MyDropDownItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem">       
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyDropDownItemTextAppearance</item>    
    </style>
    
    <style name="MyDropDownItemTextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>    
    </style>  but it certainly does not work.  Instead of android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem I tried sth with Spinner in it to mimic your style, but it did not work either.

Comment: Seems `Theme.Holo.Light` is different with AppCompat. I found         <item name="textAppearanceSearchResultTitle">@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Light.SearchResult.Title</item> In `Theme.Holo.Light`       .You can look up the theme source code to find a solution.   @Yar

Answer (score 8):

You can define the following styles in the res/styles.xml if you're using android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/myAutoCompleteTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSearchResultTitle">@style/mySearchResult</item>
</style>

<style name="myAutoCompleteTextViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="mySearchResult" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

If you're using the default SearchView, the attributes should be "android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle" and "android:textAppearanceSearchResultTitle". I've written a [post](https://medium.com/@tangbenze/how-to-style-android-searchview-suggestion-list-493578d3e0de) describing the details about this.

Comment: the only solution that works on Android 4.2. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me and the blog post is nice and succinct, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

With styles you change the background of the dropdown and the items text color

```
<!-- ToolBar -->
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/myDropDownItemStyle</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/myDropDownListViewStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="myDropDownItemStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondary_text_default_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
</style>

<style name="myDropDownListViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:background">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define suggestionRowLayout in themes.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/bluegrey_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/bluegrey_900</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/teal_500</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <!-- The layout for the search view. Be careful. -->
    <!--<item name="layout">...</item>-->
    <!-- Background for the search query section (e.g. EditText) -->
    <!--<item name="queryBackground">@color/bluegrey_400</item>-->
    <!-- Background for the actions section (e.g. voice, submit) -->
    <!--<item name="submitBackground">...</item>-->
    <!-- Close button icon -->
    <!--<item name="closeIcon">...</item>-->
    <!-- Search button icon -->
    <!--<item name="searchIcon">...</item>-->
    <!-- Go/commit button icon -->
    <!--<item name="goIcon">...</item>-->
     <!--Voice search button icon-->
    <!--<item name="voiceIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_voice_search_api_mtrl_alpha</item>-->
    <!-- Commit icon shown in the query suggestion row -->
    <!--<item name="commitIcon">...</item>-->
    <!-- Layout for query suggestion rows -->
    <item name="suggestionRowLayout">@layout/item_suggestion_place</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (white text in suggestions on white background), but all answers don't work for me. So I finally solved this with changing **textColor** attribute for **TextView** for **adapter**, attached to **AutoCompleteTextView**:

code:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = ...;
List<String> suggestions = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.dropdown_item, suggestions);
autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
```

dropdown_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      ...
/>
```