# change text color and size of SearchView drop down

Tags: android, searchview, android-styles, dropdown

I already looked at [Styling android search view and drop down list in actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789582/styling-android-search-view-and-drop-down-list-in-actionbar) and it only works if the SearchView is in the ActionBar. The problem is I have two SearchViews. The one in the ActionBar works well with the suggested changes. But the other one, which is just inside a layout, is not working. How do I fix it? I tried applying the appTheme style to it, still nothing

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use spinner way for this

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.simple_spinner_item,itemList);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,listitems);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

may be helpfull