# Android SearchView Text color

Tags: android, xamarin, styles, searchview

I am trying to make the text the user types of the search view white. "android:searchViewTextField" give an error. I can't find the right name for a global style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/_AppTheme"/>

<style name="_AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:searchViewTextField">@color/white_color</item>
 </style>
```

Is there a global style which will **only affect** the text of the Searchview and not all text boxes?

Comment: Check this out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259707/change-appcompats-searchview-text-and-hint-color/66246372#66246372

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the theme "SearchTextViewTheme"

```
<style name="SearchTextViewTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_color</item>
</style>
```

Then inside the TextView

```
<TextView
    style="@style/SearchTextViewTheme"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In fact applying theme must be explicitly defined in the layout XML. Therefore you do not have to worry about the theme affecting other text boxes

Answer (score 1):

If your targed SDK is 20 or less, the attributes Goolge uses to style the `SearchView` are hidden and you’ll end up with compilation errors if you try overriding them in your theme.

You can use the AppCompat v20 `SearchView` instead of the the native `SearchView` following this [tutorial](http://www.jayway.com/2014/06/02/android-theming-the-actionbar/). AppCompat exposes attributes like `searchViewTextField` and `searchViewAutoCompleteTextView` to change the style of the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it's done ins `Xamarin` (I based the idea from **Patrick's** answer):

```
     [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof (CustomSearchBar), typeof (CustomSearchBarRenderer))]

      namespace Bahai.Android.Renderers
      {
      public class CustomSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
     {
       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            SearchBar element = (SearchBar) this.Element;
            var native = (global::Android.Widget.SearchView) Control;

            // do whatever you want to the controls here!
            //--------------------------------------------
            // element.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
            // native.SetBackgroundColor(element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
            // native.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White.ToAndroid());

            //The text color of the SearchBar / SearchView 
            AutoCompleteTextView textField = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                (((Control.GetChildAt(0) as ViewGroup)
                    .GetChildAt(2) as ViewGroup)
                    .GetChildAt(1) as ViewGroup)
                    .GetChildAt(0);

            if (textField != null)
                textField.SetTextColor(Color.White.ToAndroid());
        }
    }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick

```
 <style name="myTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">    
    <item name="android:editTextColor">#fffff</item>
  </style>
```

The above solutions might work in java but they don't work in xamarin and i guess this solution will work in java.