# Change SearchView Text Color Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to change the search text view color in Xamarin.Android. I have tried below code so far

```
        searchView = this.Activity.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView (Resource.Id.searchView);
        searchView.SetOnQueryTextListener(this);
        var textViewId = searchView.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        var textView = (searchView.FindViewById(textViewId) as TextView);
        if (textView != null)
            textView.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.White);
```

I am getting NULL when I try to capture the `textView`

In `textViewId` I'm getting the id of the view something like `126312727`

Can anyone help me on above?

Comment: Check this out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259707/change-appcompats-searchview-text-and-hint-color/66246372#66246372

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is right out of app using `Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView`

```
var id = searchView.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("search_src_text", "id", PackageName);
var searchEditText = searchView.FindViewById<EditText>(id);
searchEditText.SetTextColor(Color.Red);
```

Comment: Thanks!! Its working, but the cursor is having the theme color. How can we change the cursor color ?

Comment: Hey @SushiHangover, Is it possible to change the cursor color too? I've tried to change the accent color but it was defined in the global theme so how to do that just for the SearchView?

Comment: @Sandeep-Systematix yes, but do not remember off the top of my head... i'll look at some of my code later...

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the below with AppCompat and CrossCurrentActivity plugin.

```
var searchEditText = (CrossCurrentActivity.Current?.Activity as MainActivity)?.FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.search_src_text);
searchEditText.SetTextColor(Color.Red);
```