# How to change text color of SearchView in Toolbar?

Tags: java, android, xml

How to change text color of SearchView in Toolbar? [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V39Wx.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the textcolor on an Android SearchView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321129/is-it-possible-to-change-the-textcolor-on-an-android-searchview)

Comment: I try this <item name="android:editTextColor">@android:color/white</item> it's change color of whole edit text in project. But I want change only SearchView text color.

Comment: Check this out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259707/change-appcompats-searchview-text-and-hint-color/66246372#66246372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
AutoCompleteTextView searchTextView = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```