# Change SearchView TextSize

Tags: android

I have the following `SearchView` implementation in the `xml`, the text entry has been cut from the top as shown in the below image. No matter what `textSize` I am putting, nothing changes.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="32dp"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
     <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you have some padding at the top which cuts letters. provide complete xml

Comment: have you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/12942258/4856245

Comment: I have added additional information to the xml in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> try this one

you have to pass your `SearchView` and `textSize` in this method

```
private void setSearchviewTextSize(SearchView searchView, int fontSize) {
        try {
            AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextViewSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("app:id/search_src_text", null, null));
            if (autoCompleteTextViewSearch != null) {
                autoCompleteTextViewSearch.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize);
            } else {
                LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0);
                LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout1.getChildAt(2);
                LinearLayout linearLayout3 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout2.getChildAt(1);
                AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) linearLayout3.getChildAt(0);
                autoComplete.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0);
            LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout1.getChildAt(2);
            LinearLayout linearLayout3 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout2.getChildAt(1);
            AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) linearLayout3.getChildAt(0);
            autoComplete.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize);
        }
    }
```

update your XML also

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center_vertical">
     <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have added additional information to the xml in my question.

Comment: its working for me in Native app, i have no idea about xamarin.

Comment: In Xamarin it's similar except you use `Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Sp` instead of `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP`.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this using a theme:

in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppSearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView" >
        <item name="android:textSize">60sp</item>
    </style>
```

And using a SearchView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            app:theme="@style/AppSearchView" // use app:theme not in style
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sv= (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
TextView searchText = (TextView)               
sv.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,12);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can directly change in theme.xml
It will affect in whole application, where it has an search view.

Eg,

```
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>

</style>
```