# Set text size of the queryHint in SearchView

Tags: android

I have a `SearchView` with a hint text in the search box.

How can i set the text size of the `queryHint`?

```xml
    <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchViewBox"
            android:layout_width="351dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:queryBackground="@null"
            android:queryHint="Search text here"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titel" />
```

Comment: Checkout this link once you will find something useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535176/how-to-set-searchview-textsize

Comment: Tx i found my answer there.